# How to perform Clear Cell Contents in an Excel Sheet by its "UsedRange" using apache-poi & java

Tags: java, automation, apache-poi

I'm trying to clear existing cell contents of excel sheet (.xlsx). not to delete the whole sheet.

using apache-poi usedrange

Comment: First do decide how you will realize the concept of `UsedRange` using `apache poi`. Then it should be easy setting cell values to `null` and/or setting cell types to `BLANK` using [Cell.setCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-).

Comment: Thanks Richter, exactly !! Is it possible to get UsedRange using Apache POI